# How can I get ancestor ids for arbitrary recursion depth in one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

**table:**

```
    id  parent_id
    --------------
    a_1 NULL
    a_2 NULL
    b_1 a_1
    c_1 b_1
    d_1 c_1
```

Now, I have id:`d_1`

How can I get `a_1`,`b_1`,`c_1` in one SQL query? (`d_1`'s ancestor ids)?

Comment: You mean d_1's ancestor ids. d_1's parent id is c_1, but you want all of the ancestors of d_1. (You might want to edit your question to clarify this). This is something that SQL does not do very well (handling arbitrary levels of hierarchy), though someone who is an expert may have a solution.

Comment: Do you have a fixed maximum recursion depth?

Comment: good question @AlbinSunnanbo, I just went with a very literal meaning of the question. I guess with LEFT JOIN and [maximum recursion depth] number of JOINS one might sufficient flexibility. For an undefined number of parents... I'd really like to see how someone creates a single SQL statement for that

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo no,not limit the recursion depth

Comment: Hope you don't mind I clarified the title.

Comment: @Nicolas78, It is doable with recursive CTE:s, but that is not available in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think you can do this in a simple SQL statement, it's a fundamental limitation of the SQL language.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248915) is a heinous stored procedure that does roughly what you want (for SQL Server). So you would need to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.id, b.id, a.id 
FROM T 
INNER JOIN T AS c on T.parent_id=c.id 
INNER JOIN T AS b ON c.parent_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN T as a ON b.parent_id = a.id
```

assuming your table's named T. untested though. not sure what happens if d doesn't have three parents, probably you don't get a thing, might try LEFT JOIN for those cases to obtain NULL values for the great parents. Also, the last JOIN isn't really necessary because you could simply select b.parent_id instead of a.id but, you know, just to drive home the pattern ;)

Comment: Note this assumes a fixed depth of the hierarchy.

Comment: yea, see my comment above, I took the question at face value, which may be the uninteresting part; with LEFT JOINs however this changes at least to an only fixed MAXIMUM depth

Comment: no. but you could use as many JOINs as you maximally want to look up and use LEFT JOIN. No idea how to make this for an infinite number of parents...